# Sequelize default connection pool size

Tags: sequelize.js

Simple question seeking a simple answer.

What is the default connection pool size for a sequelize managed pg database?

The docs don't say anything about this, however they do mention options for setting min/max idle times.

Comment: Did I answer your question? If I did, please accept my answer so people know this question is answered.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The default pooling configuration is:

```json
{
    max: 5,
    min: 0,
    idle: 10000,
    acquire: 60000,
    evict: 1000
}
```

So the default min. amount of pool connections is 0 and the default max. amount of pool connections is 5.

Source: [sequelize/src/dialects/abstract/connection-manager.js:L34](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/6f5e9556883f0ac40abdfe9ca877ccbf615bddc2/src/dialects/abstract/connection-manager.js#L34)

Comment: https://sequelize.org/master/manual/getting-started.html

  pool: {
    max: 5,
    min: 0,
    acquire: 30000,
    idle: 10000
  }
});

Answer (score 0):

Go to connection-manager.js file and you'll find this

```
const defaultPoolingConfig = {
  max: 5,
  min: 0,
  idle: 10000,
  acquire: 10000,
  evict: 10000,
  handleDisconnects: true
};
```